# Do strategic resource bonuses automatically apply to ships etc?

Tags: stellaris

In Stellaris, strategic resources provide bonuses to your empire of various kinds. I know sometimes the resources are utilized in certain buildings, research or modules but I am not sure how the bonuses are applied.

If I have Neutronium Ore for example and looking in the strategic resources menu, it says +20% armor. **Is that just automatically applied to all my ships? Is it only for new ones? Will it apply after an upgrade?**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems that strategic resources that provide bonuses to ships such as these are **automatically applied.**

[image]

When you hover over stats that would be affected by the resources, you can see it lists the bonus applied. This includes new and old ships.

When I hover over armor it says +20% which lines up with having the Neutronium.

Ones that are used for buildings are used up and go towards their construction.

Certain resources like Neutronium also automatically [unlock new research](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Technology#Neutronium_Materials) like the level V armor.

I came across [this forum](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/guide-to-strategic-resources.979079/) that lists what determines resources showing up in systems generally speaking.